# Vega-lite set color from data whilst retaining a legend

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to use values from the data in order to set the colors of the bars. I would also like this to be reflected in a legend.

So I've figured out how to use a specific color for a bar, based on a value in the data:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A bar chart that directly encodes color names in the data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "color": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
        "b": 28,
        "type": "outside"
      },
      {
        "color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
        "b": 55,
        "type": "inside"
      },
      {
        "color": "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        "b": 43,
        "type": "dew"
      }
    ]
  },  
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "type",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": { "field": "color", "type": "nominal", "legend": {}, "scale": null}
  }
}
```

Correctly colored bars:

[image: Correctly Colored Bars]

The above only works due to the `"scale": null` which prevents the legend from showing. If I remove this, then the legend shows, but the custom colors are lost and I get the rbg values showing up in the legend:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A bar chart that directly encodes color names in the data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "color": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
        "b": 28,
        "type": "outside"
      },
      {
        "color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
        "b": 55,
        "type": "inside"
      },
      {
        "color": "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        "b": 43,
        "type": "dew"
      }
    ]
  },  
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "type",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": { "field": "color", "type": "nominal", "legend": {}}
  }
}
```

Colors lost, wrong legend labels:

[image]

I can obviously get the correct legend labels with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A bar chart that directly encodes color names in the data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "color": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
        "b": 28,
        "type": "outside"
      },
      {
        "color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
        "b": 55,
        "type": "inside"
      },
      {
        "color": "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        "b": 43,
        "type": "dew"
      }
    ]
  },  
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "type",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": { "field": "type", "type": "nominal", "legend": {}}
  }
}
```

But still I don't get the colors I want:

[image]

Is it possible to have both custom colors and a legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to get custom colors to appear in a legend is to use a scale with a custom [scheme](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#scheme). For example, you could create the chart you have in mind this way:

([view in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAEZkBMAHADRTwCeADoWZAHt88YgEtofAL6sq1Wg1QBWRe0hde-UQDsxEyNNkZ5ZACwBmVer6oYhAO77DAXSoHMAW1gAnANb863pAymIRaAMYC0NoA5mToGJAAHnGQAGaihLjQ-FZBHDzWUFoC7tp4+sEJnCnpmdk2DJYF-ACO+LBa8KKIXVhSlZgRuAJecYaYtVk5zQMJuTbFpVrls5jEYXiF8dSY0CWw2mTkgsK6fKraZ3m2Dk6rCV4d0YXHXtF0ABQADOw-YF8ASmub0+jGUv1+QNUIO+7DBKn+QJcOzAkkMaIgaMkQA))

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"b": 28, "type": "outside"},
      {"b": 55, "type": "inside"},
      {"b": 43, "type": "dew"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "type",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["outside", "inside", "dew"],
        "range": ["rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I don't know of any way to draw this color scheme definition from the data, or to force a legend to be drawn when setting scale to `null`, but you could hack it by essentially drawing the legend yourself. It might look something like this:

([view in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAIJh26XWCTW8YFugebGu5PDxiAnmGRL4bm1YW24xbhsldFQdMEYlRxQwTWd6NQ1IFLxMHFAICEgKdDFWHWwwAG0NfLBgSEDw3XLIXWp2AAoABlUwbt6ASjUodnKAJgAOHsg8b0JkZu5WPFhGbUgAX3UaiDqGiObWjtGAVmOevs7BqZGcU6mZueb4lbXN6vzdsP3TQ66ek7OAyGkBuYGkAGZ7rN5qZtAB3DbvAC6GjeBUQgQCznKVRqeW2kAwugA1s0rE0tgT-IFXEpqOV8dsoAAPBmQABmjGQYk0zQe8yhj1MSm4qHixQ2lKZkG8bM53N5phGgphUAAjqx0EojNkjFRJe8avUvk1coaCfKec09hTzUb+c0RWKomJ0kyjWIaP5FbU0e6CghiqqlKwxGI7WB1uaozU-TtzdNmJ6+dC3QSiaTctNU6ZCNx4nhgSsAF6q8Z9SCwRDoIVQWAa6wCqCcsPIH14XSlOP5SDUoLxelm-0yhkRgqWn3Zx5S91T1WQJ3i10z6XoZmMWBsiJc7UHRjUfDAnXJnAhsMx93do02uVcq2mG8qx2ipdF+BB8pnsQX2PvC8o9YgA))

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A bar chart that directly encodes color names in the data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"color": "rgb(0, 0, 0)", "b": 28, "type": "outside"},
      {"color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "b": 55, "type": "inside"},
      {"color": "rgb(0, 255, 0)", "b": 43, "type": "dew"}
    ]
  },
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "color",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {},
          "scale": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "type",
      "mark": {"type": "point", "size": 80, "shape": "square", "filled": true},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "type",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"orient": "right", "title": null}
        },
        "color": {"field": "color", "type": "nominal", "scale": null}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I came to the same conclusion. I had the same idea yesterday and have a chart that looks exactly as your above, also using hconcat! Thanks for confirming